# How to use usage of Appearnce tab of Mask CE in TYPO3?

Tags: typo3, tx-mask, ext-mask

When adding `Mask` content element it doesn't reflect some setting of the `Appearance` tab at front-end, like `Layout`, `Frame`, `Space Before` or `After`, also it doesn't include the uid of content element. How can I make usage of these fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Mask elements do not use standard wrapping for rendering the content element, fortunately you can easily access them within `data` variable which contains array of `tt_content`.

To check what fields of `tt_content` are available just put the line in FE template of your Mask element:

```html
<f:debug>{data}</f:debug>
```

So you can make the wrapper `div` by yourself using simple Fluid syntax

```html
<div class="
        {f:if(condition: data.layout, then: 'frame-layout-{data.layout}')}
        {f:if(condition: data.frame_class, then: 'frame-{data.frame_class}')}
        {f:if(condition: data.space_before_class, then: 'frame-space-before-{data.space_before_class}')}
        {f:if(condition: data.space_after_class, then: 'frame-space-after-{data.space_after_class}')} ">

    <!-- your markup here -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the layouts like fluid_styled_content does - it takes care of headers, frames, spaceBefore, etc. This is also the easiest way.

First step: define the layout directories in TypoScript:

```
lib.maskContentElement.layoutRootPaths.5 = EXT:fluid_styled_content/Resources/Private/Layouts/
lib.maskContentElement.partialRootPaths.5 = EXT:fluid_styled_content/Resources/Private/Partials/
```

Second step: use the layout in your template:

```
<html xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/Fluid/ViewHelpers" data-namespace-typo3-fluid="true">
<f:layout name="Default" />

<f:section name="Main">

  <!-- your markup here -->

</f:section>

</html>
```

This also works for DCE (with corresponding TypoScript path)

Of course you can copy the layouts and partials to your theme path and make changes there, but I recommend sticking to the core functionality.